# Compare two variables with a Shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, echo

I have a script that allows me to compare these variables:

```
FT_NBR1=\'?"\"'\
FT_NBR2=rcrdmddd
```

My question is how can I pass the FT_NBRs variables to the script to execute the comparison in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the variables using your shell, then they will be available in the script.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash --
echo "${test}"
```

Export variable and run script:

```
$ export test=something
$ ./script
something
```

The way you are trying to assign values to variables will not work.

```
FT_NBR1=\'?"\"'\
FT_NBR2=rcrdmddd
```

`FT_NBR2` is fine, but `FT_NBR1` is not valid. Have a look a single vs double quotes and special character escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass environmental variables to a script with setting the variables just before. The variables will not be set in the current environment, which can be useful in some cases.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "var1: $var1"
```

and then call it with

```
$ var1=234 ./script.sh
var1: 123
$ echo "var1: $var1"
var1:
```

This works in bash. I don't know about general POSIX compability.